# How to remove trailing slash from all website pages in Magento ver. 1.14.2.2

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14

Any solution for resolving the trailing slash issue from all the website pages. The Home page is running with a trailing slash. Example -

http://www.example.com/

Apart from the Home page, the rest of the website pages are running with and without trailing slash by default.

http://www.example.com/category/sub-category.html/

How to resolve the trailing slash issue from all website pages except Home page and also if trailing slash would be resolved at once, then how would it impact the Home page.

Do we need to set a redirect rule to the new Home page without trailing slash?

Moreover, the website is currently accessible with HTTP and HTTPS versions, but by default, it is running with HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

For both categories and products you should be able to do this by setting the '`URL suffix`'. Go to the backend **System > Configuration Catalog section > Catalog** then scroll down to `Search Engine Optimisations` and give the `Product URL Suffix` and `Category URL Suffix` the value /

**Don't forget to reindex your Catalog URL Rewrites**

Comment: Currently, the URL suffix has 'html' mentioned. Are you sure replacing it with the trailing slash value - / would resolve the problem?